# How Can I Build docker image of react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, redux, dockerfile

I am developing an application with React and Redux also I want to deploy this app to AWS, Can someone suggest me way to build docker images? Also I need to build image for **build** or entire **src** folder ? Why I need Nginx?

Comment: is there any reason why you need to deploy on docker instead of deploying it as a static website?

Comment: check this blog https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-react-app/

Comment: @ArunK my app is kind of progressive web app also I received advises that docker would be great choice for CI/CD and all

Comment: You need to have a docker image with all the required packages. You can use a build tool like Jenkins to create the snapshot tar of dist folder (output of npm build command) and add that to your image. Now this image you can use for creating container. Nginx is a web server and should be installed by default in the base image.

Comment: I'm with @ArunK on that one. You should probably look into deploying this as a static website from a CDN. It would probably end up being cheaper and it would also work very well with CI / CD. If you want to discover Docker + Nginx, that's another story however.

Answer (score 3):

here is how you can build and deploy docker image on AWS

#### building the docker

- choose the appropriate  docker image,
  your modules are still npm modules, you can choose `Node` docker image.
- Build the react application, `npm run build` which will produce the `build` directory with optimised code ready for deployment
- You can use any web server to serve the static contents of the build directory

#### pushing the image

- Push the image to AWS ECR (docker registry)

#### deployment

- You could run the docker on AWS ECS in your own EC2
- You could run the docker on AWS ECS in Fargate if you dont want to use your own EC2.

Regarding nginx, I would rather setup an application load balancer. That way I can also setup ssl easily